# Django channel vs node socket.io

Tags: node.js, django, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I want to develop a real time chat application and also want to show real time graph/chart.I am confused to choose technology.I heard a lot of good things about nodejs socket.io and also heard about django channel.Can you suggest me to choose from one of them for my project?

There need a special feature though.I need to run a cron job to get data from external web service and broadcast it to all clients.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Django channels is fantastic at broadcasting and creating a chat application. I have successfully used Channels with Websocket and Redis to create a chat application. I am not sure about scalability, but since you're here with this question there may be a chance that your app may not reach a large enough usage frequency to make that an issue.